# How to detect whether Checkbox of a datagridview is checked

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
btndelete_Click()
  for each row as Datagridview Row In DGV.Rows
    If Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells(3).Value) = True Then     
      Try
        sql = "Delete from Student Where ID = '" & row.Cells(0).Value & "'"
        connect()
        cmd = New OledbCommand (sql, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      Catch ex As Exception
      End Try
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

I want to delete values in database based on checked cells in DatagridView. When I run the code and I don’t even check the cell it will still delete all.

Comment: I would step through this with the debugger and see what the values are holding. You should be able to look at the raw information the cells(3).value holds and from there see where the code runs to next. Of course, remark out the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery  and connection code until you have this figured out. Also note you're hiding any exceptions that may be thrown by not at least displaying the ex.message inside your catch block.

Comment: Yes please ID is a column in the datagridview  and also a column of a table in the database and it is Windows form

Comment: A text field in the datagridview

Comment: So did you step through and see what values are held at the time of execution of your condition statement?

Comment: Code works as posted.  The problem is somewhere else.  Make sure you are looking at the right database.

Comment: Yeah it works, but my problem is,  I wanted the code to work only if the checkbox is checked

Comment: That's what I was implying, your if condition works.

Comment: OK from experience here are 3 possible things that could be happening. 1. You are looking at the results in the wrong DB (as Lars pointed out) 2. You are iterating through the wrong DGV or 3, your column is pointing to a column that is all numbers that can be converted to boolean and is converting to true because you're off on an index. Check these 3 things to see if any holds true.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you and I am looking through

Answer (score 0):

If during the click event you aren't picking up any cells that are checked, look at your code that loads the datagrid.  You shouldn't databind during the postback in order to keep the values the user is passing back to the server.  Something along these lines:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
    dataGrid.DataSourceID = "someDataSource";
    dataGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Please come again